# Un-catchable ErrorException in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, exception, doctrine

Sometimes, my php say:

> "ErrorException : Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=X"

I tried to put a try/catch block in order to process a retry (with `\Exception` as exception class), but my try/catch block has no effect and the error is still thrown.

Have you any idea? Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

This error happens sometimes due to the packets exceed the `max_allowed_packet`

it is not PHP Exception to catch it, it is MySQL error.

can you update your `my.cnf` and add the following:

`max_allowed_packet=50M`

then restart MySQL, you should be OK.